# WP All Import : Missing Product ID

Tags: wordpress, import, export, product

I am using WP All Import to import the product and orders from one website to another. However, after I import the products for example, the product id changed. It replaced to the new one, not the same as the imported product details. I wonder if I missing something during the import process. I tried many ways, but I found no solution on how to set the product id, so that it will be stored after the import process, instead of changed.

Because of this matter, I got issue in importing orders. Since order were depends on product id to be imported. Once no product id matched, no orders will be imported.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to import product ID's because they are created in database by adding to last record ID. For example your last product in database has id of 864 so imported products will be 865 or bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are using the same Unique Key for imports.